# Which content source is responsible for updating the NumComments field?

Tags: search, content-search-web-part, crawl, comments, content-source

We're running SP13 and have a news functionality based on the standard blog site template. A content by search web part is being used to roll up the content and display it on the homepage.

We copied and then modified one of the existing display templates to show the number of comments that a post receives (internal name is "NumComments" which we mapped to a managed property, RefinableInt02).

It works okay, but frequently what happens is that the number of comments shown on the homepage is not correct: there are actually more comments to a post, so there is a delay in updating the numbers in the content search web part on the homepage.

My question is: which of the standard content sources is responsible for crawling, indexing and/or updating those comment numbers? Is it "Local SharePoint sites", "People" or "OneDrive"?

At first I thought it was Local SharePoint Sites but since comments are social content tied to a certain person (right?); perhaps it belongs to People or OneDrive content source instead?

What configuration/settings (continuous vs incremental etc) would you recommend to have it update that number of comments as quickly as possible?

Or am I searching in the wrong direction? Would be great to hear your ideas and suggestions.